# Paging3 first item removing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3

I use the paging 3 library. If necessary, I call `adapter.refresh()` to update the list. However, if you call an update on the first element of the list, and this element is deleted in the remote source, the list position will scroll to the beginning of the second page (regardless of the `getRefreshKey()` result). This situation is handled normally in other positions of the list: the deleted item simply disappears, the position of the list does not change. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?